# Some TikZ lines not printing

Tags: tikz-pgf, printing

I noticed while printing my thesis that some dashed lines do not appear on the hard copy. Here is what I get after printing:

[image]

Here's what it's supposed to look like:

[image]

I have another figure somewhere containing multiple dashed lines, where some of them show up and some of them don't. I was able to work around the issue by printing the file to a PDF printer first, and then printing *that* PDF instead.

Why does this happen? What is the scope of the issue? Does it extend beyond TikZ? It's frustrating to have to re-inspect every square inch of my printed 100-page thesis for things like this, now that I know TikZ figures do not print reliably.

Edit: Here is the code for the figure.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,titlepage,oneside,final]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext} % Lots of math symbols and environments

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\scalebox{1}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[<->] (-6,0) -- (6,0) node[right] {$y$};
    \draw[->] (0,3) -- (0,4) node[above] {$f_k(y)$};
    \draw[dotted] (0,0) -- (0,3);

    \draw[very thick,domain=-3:3,samples=200] plot (\x,{0.5+2.5*exp(-abs(\x))});
    \draw[very thick] (-5,0.6245) -- (-2.98,0.6245);
    \draw[very thick] (5, 0.6245) -- (2.98,0.6245);
    \draw[very thick] (-5,0.6245) -- (-5,0);
    \draw[very thick] (5,0.6245) -- (5,0);

    \draw[thick,dashed] (-3,1) -- (-3,-0.25) node[below] {$-Y_k$};
    \draw[thick,dashed] (3,1) -- (3,-0.25) node[below] {$Y_k$};
    \draw[thick,dashed] (-5,1) -- (-5,-0.25) node[below] {$-A_k$};
    \draw[thick,dashed] (5,1) -- (5,-0.25) node[below] {$A_k$};
    \draw[thick,dashed] (0,0) -- (0,-0.25) node[below] {$0$};

    \draw (0.5,0.5) to[in=270,out=90] (3,3) node[above] {inliers};
    \draw (4,0.3) to[in=270,out=90] (5,1.75) node[above] {outliers};
    \draw (-4,0.3) to[in=270,out=90] (-3,1.75) node[above] {outliers};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{\label{fig:lptcm}%
Schematic plot of $f_k(y)$}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please show the code that you used to generate that figure (and only as much other code as necessary to get to a complete document)? Thanks :-)

Comment: it depends on the printer, the driver, and what colors or grey scale were used for the dashes.

Comment: What's the linewidth of the dashes?

Comment: I have added the source code. The dashes are `[thick,dashed]` and the dotted line is just `[dotted]`.

Comment: Your printer must be non PS printer. It prints just fine here. Are you complilin LaTeX-->PS --> PDF ?

Comment: You can try 'print as image' or whatever the option is called for you. However, it is better to use this only for the pages you need it as it slows things down (possibly a lot). That said, I print two or three hundred pages this way in three or four batches and it is not too bad. (I need it for every page, so I cannot avoid this.)

Comment: This looks very much to me like a printer driver issue rather than a TeX/TikZ/... one: the actual PDF is fine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a printer issue.

Comment: The question is very well phrased and I want to encourage you to ask further question of such high quality, but unfortunately I also have to vote to close (printer issue).