# tikzpicture graph does not output correctly upon printing

Tags: tikz-pgf, printing

Could you please tell me why these graphs B and E would print with unwanted borders like they do in the screenshot?

[image: What is being printed]

Please note that I have applied the same setting for every graph on this page and it is only B and E have this issue erroneously.

The pdf version latex compiles is attached which looks perfect.
[image: What is supposed to be printed]

Many thanks

Edit: The following is the corrected code for the graph B. The domain of the graph was -7:7 before which caused the problem in the graph, and E had the same problem. I hope this helps!

```
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
axis x line=middle,    % put the x axis in the middle
axis y line=middle,    % put the y axis in the middle
title={$ $},
axis line style={<->}, % arrows on the axis
xlabel={$x$},          % default put x on x-axis
ylabel={$y$},          % default put y on y-axis
ticks=none
}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-2,xmax=2,ymin=-1.4,ymax=1.4
]
\addplot[thick,color=black,samples=100,domain=-2:2] {-0.55*(x^3/3-1.25^2*x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: It looks to me like the whole page is getting warped, not just the edges.  Could it be the printer or printer driver?

Comment: Did u try using a different pdf reader to see if there is any change ?

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282527/some-tikz-lines-not-printing

Comment: Without seeing some code it is difficult to help. Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue has been resolved in the question. That is, the question contains incomplete code for a solution, but no code relevant to the problem. So it isn't now of much help to anybody else.

Comment: Please answer questions in the answer space. I know, you tried and somebody told you to put it in the question for some reason. But it should have been in an answer. Just you want a complete, minimal document showing the problem (question) and a complete minimal document showing the solution (answer). Now we have an incomplete solution and no problem ... :(